# Deploying jar to Nexus using Maven Ant Task

Tags: maven, ant, nexus

I am going completely mad here. I am simply trying to upload a jar to a Nexus server using Maven Ant Task but when I run the build.xml file using ant I get the following error

```
Deploying to http://nexus.xxxx.co.uk:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/
[INFO] Retrieving previous build number from snapshot
Uploading: com/xxx/xxx-yyy-zzz/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/xxx-yyy-zzz-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to repository snapshot at http://nexus.xxxxx.co.uk:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/
Transferring 1091K from snapshot
Error writing to server
An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
 Diagnosis:

Error deploying artifact 'com.xxx-yyy-zzz': Error deploying artifact: Error transferring file
Error writing to server
```

This is what my build.xml file looks like

```
<project name="deploy" default="mvn-deploy" xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">

    <path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar"/>
    <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml"
             uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"
             classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath"/>

    <artifact:remoteRepository id="snapshot" url="http://nexus.xxxx.co.uk:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/">
        <releases enabled="false"/>
        <snapshots enabled="true"/>
    </artifact:remoteRepository>

    <target name="mvn-deploy">
        <artifact:deploy file="/path/to/jar/xxx-yyy-zzz-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
                         uniqueVersion="false">
            <remoteRepository refid="snapshot">
                <authentication username="username" password="password"/>
            </remoteRepository>
            <pom file="/path/to/pom/pom.xml"/>
        </artifact:deploy>
    </target>
</project>
```

I think I have read every blog post/stackoverflow post, ant documentation page out there and still cant work out why this doesnt work.

On the Nexus server this is what the logs show (request.log)

```
77.101.44.67 - - [16/Apr/2020:12:08:03 +0000] "PUT /repository/maven-snapshots/com/xxx/xxx-yyy-zzz/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/xxx-yyy-zzz-3.0.0-20200416.120803-3.jar HTTP/1.1" 401 1117368 0 1 "maven-artifact/2.2.1 (Java 1.8.0_31; Mac OS X 10.13.6)" [qtp615812221-41545]
77.101.44.67 - - [16/Apr/2020:12:08:03 +0000] "PUT /repository/maven-snapshots/com/xxx/xxx-yyy-zzz/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/xxx-yyy-zzz-3.0.0-20200416.120803-3.jar HTTP/1.1" 401 1117368 0 1 "maven-artifact/2.2.1 (Java 1.8.0_31; Mac OS X 10.13.6)" [qtp615812221-41531]
```

So as you can see from the logs, I am getting a 401 HTTP response code, which means Unauthorized. Also the 3rd parameter in the log lines above should show the username, so this kind of leans towards ant not passing the username and password through when upload the file, and its failing because you need credentials to upload the file.

Its defo not a Nexus configuration issue or nexus user permissions issue because if I use maven and run

```
mvn deploy
```

With the same info it uploads the jar without an issue

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated before I have no hair left...

Comment: Why are you using maven ant taks instead of Maven itself?

Comment: @khmarbaise - I am actually trying to debug a grails plugin, grails release plugin. I am trying to deploy a grails plugin to nexus but it keeps failing and after debugging the plugin itself I have worked out that the plugin uses maven ant tasks to transfer the file to nexus, hence my question. So I wanted to take out the context of grails from the question because I don't think its anything to do with grails or the plugin but the maven ant task instead, as I get the exact same behaviour from the grails plugin and this ant target above.

Comment: The `maven-ant-tasks` is retired. It was last published in 2014 per the [website](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) and hasn't been supported for a long time. I'd strongly recommend finding another option. One issue I am aware of is that sometimes the plugin refuses to properly consider the `settings.xml` file.

Comment: @user944849 - thanks for making me aware of the maven ant tasks being retired I didnt know that. Thing is what I am ultimately testing is using AntBuilder class and antlib to make the same request to the Nexus server. I was just assuming that they are doing the same thing as the maven ant tasks hence why I was trying to test with this. So I guess I can try test with the Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks but I am not sure if that is the same as what antlib and AntBuilder and doing. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 2):

So all the credit here has to go to @user944849 for making me aware that the maven ant tasks are actually retired now as per the [website](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html)

[image: Maven Ant Tasks Website]

Right at the top of the page it plainly says its retired and also that its been replaced with the Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks. So I gave that a go and just like magic that worked first go.

I also got it to work with handling sending snapshots and releases to the correct repos. This is handled by the pom that you link and the version of the project, SNAPSHOT version goes to snapshot repo and non SNAPSHOT version to the releases repo

For anyone finding this, this is the build.xml file I created and used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:resolver="antlib:org.apache.maven.resolver.ant">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.resolver.ant" resource="org/apache/maven/resolver/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="lib" includes="maven-resolver-ant-tasks-1.2.0-uber.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <resolver:authentication username="user" password="pass" id="auth"/>

    <resolver:remoterepo id="ossrh" url="http://nexus.xxxx.co.uk:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/"
                type="default" releases="false" snapshots="true" updates="always" checksums="fail">
        <resolver:authentication refid="auth"/>
    </resolver:remoterepo>

    <resolver:remoterepo id="rao" url="http://nexus.xxxxx.co.uk:8081/repository/maven-releases/">
        <resolver:releases enabled="true" updates="daily" checksums="warn"/>
        <resolver:snapshots enabled="false"/>
        <resolver:authentication refid="auth"/>
    </resolver:remoterepo>

    <resolver:remoterepos id="all">
        <resolver:remoterepo refid="ossrh"/>
        <resolver:remoterepo refid="rao"/>
    </resolver:remoterepos>

    <resolver:artifacts id="producedArtifacts">
        <resolver:artifact file="/path/to/jar/xxx-yyy-zzz-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    </resolver:artifacts>

    <resolver:pom file="/path/to/pom/pom.xml" id="pom"/>

    <target name="deploy">
        <resolver:deploy artifactsref="producedArtifacts">
            <resolver:remoterepo refid="rao"/>
            <resolver:snapshotrepo refid="ossrh" />
        </resolver:deploy>
    </target>
</project>
```

Only major gotcha here was the taskdef at the top of the file needs the jar for the maven resolver ant tasks. I found that the one in maven central was giving me dependency errors when I ran my build file , so what I did instead was download the source from the [website](http://maven.apache.org/resolver-ant-tasks/download.cgi), and then I ran

```
mvn package -DskipTests=true
```

Reason I ran skip tests was some of the tests were failing for some reason, I guess you could try and work out why and remove that switch.

You will find in the target directory will be the Uber jar, copy that into your lib directory and then it all works like magic.

Happy ant'ing :)